Small Offset in QGIS Reprojection from WGS84 to ED50
I have a .shp in QGIS in EPSG:32637 (WGS84/UTM Zone 37N) and I want to reproject it to ED50, which is in this case EPSG:23037. When I do it manually in in QGIS, the reprojection works fine and both files overlap when they are loaded in QGIS.
However, I am using ogr2ogr in order to automatize this process, and whenever I use it and load the output file to QGIS, it has a small offset with respect to the input shapefile.
The command I'm using is this:
      ogr2ogr -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:32637 -t_srs EPSG:23037 output.shp input.shp       

I have both GDAL and PROJ updated, so it's not a problem of the version.
Does anyone know why this would happen?
I have seen that when I do it in QGIS, the log that is using is something like this:
{ 'CONVERT_CURVED_GEOMETRIES' : False, 'INPUT' : 'input.shp', 'OPERATION' : '+proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=utm +zone=37 +ellps=WGS84 +step +proj=push +v_3 +step +proj=cart +ellps=WGS84 +step +proj=helmert +x=89.05 +y=87.03 +z=124.56 +step +inv +proj=cart +ellps=intl +step +proj=pop +v_3 +step +proj=utm +zone=37 +ellps=intl', 'OUTPUT' : 'output.shp', 'TARGET_CRS' : QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:23037') }

Maybe I should include these transformations in my ogr2ogr command?
And if so, what would be the syntax of the command?

are you sure that both programs are using the same transform?

I don't know, really. I have been using this ogr2ogr command in different projects with different EPSG and it worked fine. But now, when transforming to ED50, it has this small shift in the data so I thought maybe I could add some additional parameters to the ogr2ogr call to see if the result was more exact...
